# parse custom receiver not getting called

Tags: android, push-notification, parse-platform

I am trying to implement parse push notification in my android project. to understand, I am giving some project flow.

- saving user details on personal server using php API
- server send me some push notification.

I get notification but I am not getting any action, data in that push notification in my custom broadcast receiver.

Here is my Android Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

```
<permission
    android:name="com.mypackage.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.mypackage.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<application     
    android:name="com.mypackage.myappe.MyApplication"   
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/dwtlogo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
    <receiver
        android:name="com.mypackage.myapp.MyCustomReceiver"
        android:exported="false" android:enabled="true">                 
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.mypackage.myapp.MESSAGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

```
<category android:name="com.mypackage.myapp" />
```

```
</application>
```

Here is MyApplication.java

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Parse.initialize(this, "xxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxx");

    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
    defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);

    PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(getApplicationContext(), DashBoardActivity.class);

    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();

    ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
    //String deviceToken= (String) installation.get("deviceToken");
    //Toast.makeText(this, "Device token="+deviceToken, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    PushService.subscribe(this, "Wake_up", DashBoardActivity.class);
}
```

And here is my custom receiver in which i am trying to get action and data which server sending me but my custom receiver not getting called.

```
String action = intent.getAction();
            Log.d(TAG, "got action " + action );
            if (action.equals("com.mypackage.myapp.MESSAGE"))
            {
                String channel = intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Channel");
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));

                Log.d(TAG, "got action " + action + " on channel " + channel + " with:");
                Iterator itr = json.keys();
                while (itr.hasNext()) {
                    String key = (String) itr.next();
                    //if (key.equals("customdata"))
                    //{
                        Intent pupInt = new Intent(context, ShowPopup.class);
                        pupInt.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
                        context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(pupInt);
                    //}
                    Log.d(TAG, "..." + key + " => " + json.getString(key));
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "JSONException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Even no any log getting printed.  Here is php server code which sending me push notification.

```
$data = array(
                           'channel' => $chnl,
                           'action' => 'com.mypackage.myapp.MESSAGE',
                           'data' => array(
                                       'alert' => $message,
                                       'sound' => 'push.caf',
                           'photourl' => $imageurl,
                                   )
                           );
```

But i don't understand where i need to get this data so i can show image after receiving push notification.

Please give me any hint or reference.

Comment: Are you sure that is sending the notification?, Does the server that sent the notification by curl?

Answer (score 0):

Adding receiver for `GcmBroadcastReceiver` should help. As given out in the [tutorial here](https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications).

Other [reference](https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#receiving/Android).

```
<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

    <!--
      IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.tutorials.pushnotifications" to match your app's package name.
    -->
    <category android:name="com.parse.tutorials.pushnotifications" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```